# How can I find out the instruction format of a RISC-V instruction

Tags: riscv

Is there a way to find out the instruction format (R/I/S/B/U/J) from the `opcode` field `[6:0]` of the instruction? I searched the ISA manual but couldn't find it. That is quite important to decode the instruction, or did I miss something essential?

Comment: See Table 24.2 in [riscv-spec-20191213.pdf](https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/riscv-spec-20191213.pdf).  Also see the [RISC V green sheet](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1617/ECAD+Arch/files/docs/RISCVGreenCardv8-20151013.pdf), which is handy but missing the actual opcodes.  Also note that when the first 2 bits are 11, it designates a 32-bit instruction, so as seen in Table 24.1, assuming (or knowing) the instruction is in the base set (which are 32-bits wide), we need only look up 5 opcode bits.

Comment: Did you find any answer by any chance?